# Piecewise regression python

Tags: python, linear-regression, piecewise

I am trying to do a piecewise linear regression in Python and the data looks like this,

[image]

I need to fit 3 lines for each section. Any idea how? I am having the following code, but the result is shown below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib
    import matplotlib.cm as cm
    import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from scipy import optimize

    def piecewise(x,x0,x1,y0,y1,k0,k1,k2):
        return np.piecewise(x , [x <= x0, np.logical_and(x0<x, x< x1),x>x1] , [lambda x:k0*x + y0, lambda x:k1*(x-x0)+y1+k0*x0 lambda x:k2*(x-x1) y0+y1+k0*x0+k1*(x1-x0)])

    x1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ,11, 12, 13, 14, 15,16,17,18,19,20,21], dtype=float)
    y1 = np.array([5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 28.92, 42.81, 56.7, 70.59, 84.47, 98.36, 112.25, 126.14, 140.03,145,147,149,151,153,155])
    y1 = np.flip(y1,0)
    x = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ,11, 12, 13, 14, 15,16,17,18,19,20,21], dtype=float)
    y = np.array([5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 28.92, 42.81, 56.7, 70.59, 84.47, 98.36, 112.25, 126.14, 140.03,145,147,149,151,153,155])
    y = np.flip(y,0)

    perr_min = np.inf
    p_best = None
    for n in range(100):
        k = np.random.rand(7)*20
        p , e = optimize.curve_fit(piecewise, x1, y1,p0=k)
        perr = np.sum(np.abs(y1-piecewise(x1, *p)))
        if(perr < perr_min):
            perr_min = perr
            p_best = p

    xd = np.linspace(0, 21, 100)
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x1, y1, "o")
    y_out = piecewise(xd, *p_best)
    plt.plot(xd, y_out)
    plt.show()
```

data with fit
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Your images haven't shown up

Comment: I attempted to run the code you posted, and it seems to be missing import statements. Would you please post an entire working example?

Comment: Hi, Just added the import statements...

Comment: Question: can you use a single equation, or for this specific case are you set on a piecewise model?

Comment: I cannot use a single equation as it is a scientific data and the 3 zones in the curve has different properties. So, looking for piece wise fit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple method (without iteration, without initial guess) can solve this problem.

The method of calculus comes from page 30 of this paper : https://fr.scribd.com/document/380941024/Regression-par-morceaux-Piecewise-Regression-pdf (copy below).

[image]

The next figure shows the result :

[image]

The equation of the fitted function is :

[image]

Or equivalently :

[image]

*H*  is the Heaviside function.

[image]

In addition, the details of the numerical calculus are given below :

[image]

Comment: Do you know if there's a Python package for it?

Comment: Probably not. But writing a computer program of this kind is not difficult.

Comment: Sounds right. Before I dive into the source you provided - does it generalize well to m (parametrized) segments?

Comment: Theoretically I would say yes. But when the number of segments increases the matrixes become more and more big and the calculus less accurate for scattered data. In practice I am afraid that the number of segments be strongly  limited due to numerical calculus contingencies and increasing deviations resulting from the scatter of the experimental data.

Comment: Computationally, it's just an mxm matrix inversion (and similar operations), right? It's not like an operation on a 20x20 matrix should be prohibitively hard... unless I misunderstand the math part?

Comment: Yes, it is just matrix inversion and roots of polynomial equation. But the more they are terms, the more the deviation on the final result is large due to  the scatter on the initial data.